# Likert Conundrum?

Tags: likert, scales

I am a bit confused as how to derive information from two dependent 7-point likert type questions.

The First question asks : How important is the activity to you?
The second question aksa: How successful were you in the activity?

The idea here is that I want to say mathimatically that success in activities important to the person are more fulfilling then in unimportant activities. However I also want to say that failure to succed is more devestating in more important activities than less important ones.

I was thinking to label the first scale (1 to 7) and the second (-3 to 3) and then multiply them, But I need some reference in orer to do this

SO my two questions are

1) Am I on the right track
2) can someone provide a source justifying what i'm doing here

Comment: It looks that you aren't about testing your supposition about fulfilment, only want to claim it, by means of creating  a corresponding index. Then your idea is right, for me. At least one of possible ones. I don't think that anybody can ask you sources to justify it. It is obvious mathematically. Weighting is multiplication.

Comment: Note that your idea is OK if you agree to treat likert rating scale as interval (not ordinal)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach works only if you want to assume your variables are on the interval scale. I don't think it's a reasonable assumption because the differences between values can't be quantified.

You have several possibilities:

- Gamma (concordance and discordance)
- Kendall's tau-b
- Somer's D